# Bash comes to windows 10

Tags: bash, windows-10

Today all I see on my Facebook is news of Microsoft working with Ubuntu to bring [bash to windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJGqZHQzNRo)

- How to download it? From Ubuntu? Windows? Nothing in Windows store.
- Why they  keep saying Ubuntu bash? is it different from real bash
  that you run on Arch or whatever?
- Is it possible to do do killall? fork?
- Is it possible to install zsh?
- Will Canonical maintain it? Or are the updates coming from bash repos?

Comment: @kos thought about it to be honnest, but I saw the blog post on ubuntu, so I thought it's more related to ubuntu than windows, even though it runs on windows. 1- it's called ubuntu user space, 2- linux users using windows are more excited about it than windows users, windows superusers probably will stick to powershell. 3- Canonical did the hard work and advertized the event. But yeah, it's one of those questions where I really am confused where to ask it.

Comment: How could questions about an Ubuntu branded product be better suited for any other StackExchange site than AskUbuntu?

Comment: @LiveWireBT I see that point, and I agree it's Ubuntu-related. But then the question becomes: where do we draw the line? Would you be favorable to support it? I'm not necessarily against this, I just think that it's something to take into account.

Comment: @kos You can draw the line where the Ubuntu user space ends, which means we don't have to support issues caused by the *Windows Subsystem for Linux*. :) It's similar to *official* Ubuntu phones and tablets (supported devices with maintained kernels) just without a Linux kernel (that's where Microsoft is responsible) and not as terrible as the Chromebook hackery where users are lead to believe that they run a normal Ubuntu setup that can do everything Ubuntu usually can do for them and where nobody feels responsible for clearing up the confusion.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I don't have a definitive stance on this, but "Bash on Windows 10" technically is not an official Ubuntu flavour. So currently is not on-topic per the Help Center (which mentions Canonical's services, not Canonical's products). I think this should be brought to Meta first.

Comment: @LiveWireBT http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do-we-support, you may wish to weigh in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It's not available yet, it will become available first to windows insiders.
2. They keep saying Ubuntu, because it's more than just Bash, it's a Ubuntu user space.
3. Some things will work, but some things won't.  It's a little too early to tell.  I wouldn't expect you to be able to kill any windows applications from inside your bash shell.  Certain things like screen, tmux, don't work yet.
4. No idea, I doubt it.
5. I don't think anyone besides Canonical and Microsoft fully understand how their commitments to each other will work.  I think it's safe to say Microsoft wouldn't have went in without a commitment from Canonical.

Answer (score 5):

Update 2016-08-09:

- eWeek: Risk From Linux Kernel Hidden in Windows 10 Exposed at Black Hat ([1](http://www.eweek.com/security/risk-from-linux-kernel-hidden-in-windows-10-exposed-at-black-hat.html), [2](https://www.blackhat.com/us-16/briefings.html#alex-ionescu) via [3](http://www.golem.de/news/linux-unter-windows-10-neues-einfallstor-fuer-schadsoftware-1608-122590.html))

---

Update 2016-04-08:

> - How to download it? From Ubuntu? Windows? Nothing in Windows store.

It was just released with the latest preview so you currently need to set your Windows Installation to receive Insider Preview builds in the fast ring under *Settings* -> *Updates & security* -> *Advanced options*. Then update to the latest build.

- Go to *Turn Windows features on or off* in desktop/legacy settings and check the box for *Windows Sybsytem for Linux*.
- Enable *Developer mode* in *Settings* -> *Updates & security*
- Run `bash` from the start menu and confirm the message to download and install Ubuntu on Windows. The Ubuntu environment will greet you once the installation finished.

  - To further improve my Ubuntu experience on Windows I did set the background color to RGB 48 10 36, installed the Ubuntu Mono font and added it as an available font to the registry with the following command from an elevated command prompt:

    ```
    reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont" /v 00 /t reg_sz /d "Ubuntu Mono"
    ```

    Related questions:

    - [How to change the Windows XP console font?](https://superuser.com/q/5035/252532)
    - [How to enable the new console in Windows 10 and what are its defaults?](https://superuser.com/q/954425/252532)

> - Why they keep saying Ubuntu bash? is it different from real bash that you run on Arch or whatever?

The shortcut *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows* points to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~` and the file description in the details reads *"Microsoft Bash Launcher"*. While you can manage (install, uninstall, update) the environment with `lxrun` running `bash.exe` seems to be the primary way to interact with this environment.

**Edit:** Another Downfall parody titled *"Hitler uses Docker"* makes fun of current tech cargo cult. Here is a [transcript as SRT](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15793938/) in case you cannot find or watch the video.

> - Is it possible to install zsh?

Yes, but it doesn't work properly at the moment. I tried setting `dash` as a login shell but it's also getting ignored in the current implementation. That's all I found out so far.

---

Dustin Kirkland was involved with this and he published 2 posts on his blog about it:

- [Ubuntu on Windows — The Ubuntu Userspace for Windows Developers](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/03/ubuntu-on-windows.html)
- [Still have questions about Bash and Ubuntu on Windows?](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/03/questions-and-answers-about-bash-and.html)

> Just a guess, but it sounds like they've got a sort of mini-VM running a command line only Ubuntu.

That's not correct, excerpt from Dustin's blog:

> *"Right, so just Ubuntu running in a virtual machine?"*  Nope!…
>
> *"Ah, okay, so this is Ubuntu in a container then?"*  Nope!…
>
> *"Hum, well it's like cygwin perhaps?"*  Nope!… Here, we're talking about **bit-for-bit, checksum-for-checksum Ubuntu ELF binaries running directly in Windows**.
>
> [long pause]
>
> *"So maybe something like a Linux emulator?"*  Now you're getting warmer!  A team of sharp developers at Microsoft has been hard at work adapting some Microsoft research technology to basically perform real time translation of Linux syscalls into Windows OS syscalls.  Linux geeks can think of it sort of the inverse of "wine" -- Ubuntu binaries running natively in Windows.  Microsoft calls it their "Windows Subsystem for Linux".  (No, it's not open source at this time.)
>
> …
>
> So as part of the engineering work, I needed to wrap the stock Ubuntu root filesystem into a Windows application package (.appx) file for suitable upload to the Windows Store.

A few slides from one of the presentations:

[image]

So this is similar to [User-mode Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux) and [coLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_Linux), but Microsoft apparently built it's own implementation that doesn't require running a Linux kernel.

[image]
[image]

The community from Microsoft's point of view and what they are planning.

Finally [Ubundows Unlimited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAzYj.jpg), yay.

Answer (score 4):

There's some info from an announcement about it on Windows' blog [Run Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/). Here are some excerpts:

> Many of you told us that working with open-source tools on Windows is often a struggle and that you would like Microsoft to make it easier to use these tools on Windows.
>
> To accomplish this, we built new infrastructure within Windows – the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) – upon which we **run a genuine Ubuntu user-mode image** provided by our great partners over at Canonical, creators of Ubuntu Linux.
>
> The result is that you can now run native Bash on Ubuntu on Windows!
>
> [image]
>
> You can now:
>
> - run Bash scripts, Linux command-line tools like sed, awk, grep, and you can even try Linux-first tools like Ruby, Git, Python, etc. directly on Windows.
> - You can also access your Windows filesystem from within Bash allowing you to work on the same set of files using your preferred Windows tools or Linux command-line tools
>
> But Caveat Emptor (Buyer Beware!):
>
> - **it’s marked as beta for a reason:** We know that **there are some rough edges** and that **some things will break!**
> - **This is not a server platform** upon which you will host websites, run server infrastructure, etc.
> - Bash and Linux tools cannot interact with Windows applications and tools, and vice-versa. So you won’t be able to run Notepad from Bash, or run Ruby in Bash from PowerShell.

Just a guess, but from their wording *"Ubuntu user-mode image"* it *sounds* like they've got a sort of mini-VM running a command line only Ubuntu. Apparently nNot really a *mini-VM* though, more like a "Reverse-WINE" Linux emulator for running linux code more directly (overlapping concepts of VM & emulator though).